# Split rows into m parts and build the average of each part [SQLite]

Tags: sql, sqlite

I've got the following problem.

Given a table consisting basically of two columns, a timestamp and a value, I need to reduce n rows between to timestamps down to m data rows by averaging both, value and timestamp.

Let's say I want all data between times 15 and 85 in a maximum of 3 data rows.

```
time | value
10   | 7
20   | 6
30   | 2
40   | 9
50   | 4
60   | 3
70   | 2
80   | 9
90   | 2

Remove unneeded rows and split them into 3 parts

20   | 6
30   | 2

40   | 9
50   | 4
60   | 3

70   | 2
80   | 9

Average them

25   | 4
50   | 8
75   | 5.5
```

I know how to remove the unwanted rows by including a WHERE, how to average a given set of rows but can't think of a way on how to split the wanted dataset into m parts.

Any help and ideas appreciated!

I use SQLite which doesn't make this any easier and can't switch to any other dialect sadly.

I tried to group the rows based on row number and count of rows without success. The only other solution that came to my mind was getting the count of affected rows and UNION m SELECTs having a limit and offset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got it working. My problem was that I did integer division by accident.

The formula I use to group the items is:

```
group = floor ( row_number / (row_count / limit) )
```

The full SQL-query looks something like this:

```
SELECT
    avg(measurement_timestamp) AS measurement_timestamp,
    avg(measurement_value) AS average
FROM (
     SELECT
          (SELECT COUNT(*)
               FROM measurements_table
                    WHERE measurement_timestamp > start_time AND measurement_timestamp < end_time)
           AS row_count,

           (SELECT COUNT(0)
                FROM measurements_table t1
                     WHERE t1.measurement_timestamp < t2.measurement_timestamp
                     AND t1.measurement_timestamp > start_time AND t1.measurement_timestamp < end_time
                     ORDER BY measurement_timestamp ASC )
           AS row_number,

           *
           FROM measurements_table t2
           WHERE t2.measurement_timestamp > start_time AND t2.measurement_timestamp < end_time
           ORDER BY measurement_timestamp ASC)
GROUP BY CAST((row_number / (row_count / ?)) AS INT)

* the limit has to be a float
```